# Firemonkey TTakePhotoFromCameraAction.OnDidFinishTaking causes my app to restart

Tags: android, delphi, camera, firemonkey

Sorry if this is not the best title, this is my first question here.

I'm developing a mobile app to read barcodes. In my app there is a login form before the main form loads. On the main form I put action list and add `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` action to open the device camera and take photo using it. So far is working well, I'm following the tutorial [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Taking_and_Sharing_a_Picture,_and_Sharing_Text_(iOS_and_Android)).

But after pressing the yes button after taking photo, my app returns to the login form where I assume it is restarted while it should be back to the main form where I call the action.

So what am i missing here. The code I use is the same as the tutorial above.

I'm using Delphi XE 6 update 1

Please let me know if I miss some information you need. Thanks in advance

Iwan

Comment: Can you add the code from the yes button? Where is it directing you to go after execution?

Comment: When you say "I assume it is restarted" - don't assume, check. What happens when you run it under the debugger? Does it actually terminate (the IDE will show you) or does it do something else?

Comment: So when the action get executed, it will show the device's native camera viewer, then after i press the capture button of the camera, it is showing the result and a yes and no button, when i press the yes button, it is showing my login form again. @David M i assume it is restarted because i have a login form showing up at apps loading then i close it so if it is showing the login form again then it should be restarting the apps.I Can't debug it because i still failed to do it under XE5,and got no time to prepare and test debugging it under XE6.I'm using virtual machine so it is harder

Comment: I just notice my post has been edited, thanks @Deepend for correcting the grammar, it seems my English is still poor :D

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the code where your login form is shown so you can check why it is shown? That will show you if it is because the app was restarted, or if it got there by another path. (Note if your app is restarted the IDE may no longer be attached, and the IDE will say this! So in that case trace through what happens when the Yes button is pressed.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidM, but that is a problem, because i can't set my Delphi environment for debugging android app, but i will try to debug it another way by writing to a text file to see what happen. Thanks for the tip, i will try it first

Comment: I've had a similar problem. I had a ScaleBy:single property on my form that was giving me this problem. I have no clue why but after renaming it I didn't have the problem anymore.

Comment: Use here TButton instead TSpeedButton or other buttons

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem. To fix, in your android device, go to Settings > Developer options, uncheck 'Do not keep activities'.